# Invoke method doesn't work

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, invoke

I have problem with my Winforms C# program. I want to display a progressbar while files are being copied from a local disk to a network disk, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Once I had this problem in WPF thenI solved it using 'Dispatcher' but in Winforms I guess there is no something like this. Code below, thanks for help.

```
private void copyFiles(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
{
        string SourcePath, DestinationPath;
        int i = 0, idOperatDetail, udane = 0;
        OperatDetail operatDetail = null;

        if (circularProgressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => circularProgressBar1.Enabled = true));
            circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => circularProgressBar1.Visible = true));
            circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => circularProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee));
        }
        else
        {
            circularProgressBar1.Enabled = true;
            circularProgressBar1.Visible = true;
        }

        foreach (string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".tif")))
        {
            i++;
        }

        if (i != 0)
        {
            // Jest urobek to utworz foldery
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));                        
                }
            }

            foreach (string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".tif")))
            {
                string tempSchemat = sourceFile.Replace(SourcePath, "");
                var txt = tempSchemat.Split(new[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string schemat = "digitalizacja_" + txt[0].ToLower();

                if (operatDetailsUtils.DidDatabaseExists(schemat) == 0)
                {
                    operatDetail = operatDetailsUtils.GetOperatDetailIdByPath(schemat, sourceFile); // Pobierz ten szczegół z bazy danych
                    if (operatDetail != null) //  If file have record in database then get its metadata
                    {
                        idOperatDetail = operatDetail.Id;
                        Image img = Image.FromFile(sourceFile);
                        long size = (new FileInfo(sourceFile).Length);
                        int width = img.Width;
                        int height = img.Height;
                        float horResolution = img.HorizontalResolution;
                        float verResolution = img.VerticalResolution;
                        img.Dispose();
                        string destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath);
                      //  if (size < FreeSpace(DestinationPath)) // Walidacja rozmiaru pliku kopiowanego
                        {
                                File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
                                Image imgDest = Image.FromFile(destinationFile);
                                long sizeDest = (new FileInfo(destinationFile).Length);
                                int widthDest = imgDest.Width;
                                int heightDest = imgDest.Height;
                                float horResolutionDest = imgDest.HorizontalResolution;
                                float verResolutionDest = imgDest.VerticalResolution;
                                imgDest.Dispose(); // Porównanie metadanych
                                if ((size != sizeDest) || (width != widthDest) || (height != heightDest) || (horResolution != horResolutionDest) || (verResolution != verResolutionDest))
                                {
                                    File.Delete(destinationFile); // Metadane sie nie zgadzaja
                                    slog.Error($"Plik o scieżce {destinationFile} ma inne metadane niż {sourceFile}. Został on usunięty ze względu na to, że został źle skopiowany");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    udane++;
                                    operatDetailsUtils.UpdatePath(schemat, idOperatDetail, destinationFile);
                                    File.Delete(sourceFile);
                                    slog.Info($"Plik {sourceFile} został poprawnie skopiowany na dysk sieciowy, a więc został usunięty z dysku lokalnego.");
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slog.Error($"W bazie danych {schemat} w tabeli OPERAT_SZCZEGOLY nie istnieje plik o ścieżce {sourceFile} i nie został on skopiowany");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    slog.Error($"Baza danych {schemat} nie istnieje!");
                }
            }

            circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => circularProgressBar1.Enabled = false));
            circularProgressBar1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => circularProgressBar1.Visible = false));                      
    }
```

Comment: Read [ask], create a [mcve] (this is too much code) and explain how it "doesn't work".

Comment: we'll need the error...in general though...you shouldnt need to loop 3 times through the same files...only once...and you only need one generic method to toggle enabled/visible...and to call it..it can be smart enough in that method to decide whether to invoke itself or not

Comment: Anything that touches a UI control will need to be invoked while in another thread. so  `circularProgressBar1.Visible` and alike is probably your guy

Comment: Your code should work and should display the progressbar. How are you calling the method? Are you using `Task name = Task( ()=> copyFiles("",""););`

Comment: I using only this what you see.

Comment: All answers don`t solved my problem. Progress Bar shows after the copy process is finished, not parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand why you ask if Invoke is required, cause its required if you want to access the GUI from an seperate Thread.

Put every GUI changing method inside the invoke method and it should work.

Like this:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressPercentage;
            }));
```

Comment: He's most probably using async/task and changing the control within the method that's why he's invoking.

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean up your code. Also, try to call that method, for example, in button event. Call it using this:

```
Task name = Task( ()=> copyFiles("Source File"," Destination File"););
name.Start();
```

**Update 2:** Downvote? Tough crowd. Anyway, I think just remove your **Image class**. That seems to be consuming the whole task. If you're just using that for verification, I think FileInfo.Length is already sufficient enough.

**Update 1**: I've tried your code except for the database part and the progressbar is working for me.

```
        private void copyFiles(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
        {
            List<string> ext = new List<string>() { ".JPG", ".JPEG", ".TIF", ".PNG" };
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath);

            Action shower = () =>
            {
                circularProgressBar1.Enabled = true;
                circularProgressBar1.Visible = true;
                circularProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            };
            BeginInvoke(shower);

            var sourceFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => ext.Contains(f.Extension));
            int num = sourceFiles.Count();

            foreach(FileInfo fi in sourceFiles)
            {
                string newFilePath;
                if (!Directory.Exists(DestinationPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);
                }
                newFilePath = Path.Combine(DestinationPath, fi.Name);

                File.Copy(fi.FullName, newFilePath, true);

                if(fi.Length != new FileInfo(newFilePath).Length)
                {
                    File.Delete(newFilePath);
                }
            }

            Action hider = () =>
            {
                circularProgressBar1.Enabled = false;
                circularProgressBar1.Visible = false;
                circularProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            };

            BeginInvoke(hider);
        }
```

Comment: Still progress bar shows only when copying process is finished. I used Task and Invoke and I still don`t know why.